# How to fix LSI MegaRaid RAID5 after 1 disk failed

Tags: lsi, megaraid

My LSI MegaRaid just told me one disk is "UBad" which I assume means it failed:

```
EID:Slt DID State DG     Size Intf Med SED PI SeSz Model                Sp Type 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
252:7    13 UBad   F 2.728 TB SATA HDD N   N  512B WDC WD30EFRX-68EUZN0 U  -
```

I have a hot spare installed:

```
EID:Slt DID State DG     Size Intf Med SED PI SeSz Model                Sp Type 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
252:6    14 DHS    0 2.728 TB SATA HDD N   N  512B WDC WD30EFRX-68EUZN0 D -
```

but the status of the hot spare didn't change. Is it being used to save my RAID array?

If not, how do I tell the controller to add the hot spare to the disk group 0?

Comment: Isn't "ubad" = Unconfigured Bad? Is it possible the bad drive was never added to the array? How many drives in the array?

Comment: I think you have a point. I have 6 drives. 4 of them are in the RAID5 array. Each disk is 3TB and the RAID array is 9TB. For some reason, I may have two hot spares :-) How do get the UBad -> DHS? Or how do I add it to the RAID5 array?

Comment: i would pull out the ubad drive and try reseating it, if still bad you'll need to replace it.

Comment: For other people finding this question: It might be that you had two hot spares and one of them was used to replace a failed drive that was then marked as `UBad`. I just had a RAID1 array where one drive was showing as `Failed`. I added another drive as a hot spare and immediately the `Failed` drive changed to `UBad`, while the hot spare showed as `Rbld`.

Answer (score 3):

First, get some information about your controller, volumes and drive:

```
storcli /c0 show all
```

`/c0` is the controller to check. If unsure, try `/cALL` and look for a line like `Controller =` to get the controller numbers.

We need EID and Slot/Slt from the output. The `TOPOLOGY` or `PD LIST` are good:

```
TOPOLOGY :
========

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DG Arr Row EID:Slot DID Type  State BT     Size PDC  PI SED DS3  FSpace TR 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 0 -   -   -        -   RAID5 Optl  Y  8.185 TB dflt N  N   none N      N  
 0 0   -   -        -   RAID5 Optl  Y  8.185 TB dflt N  N   none N      N  
 0 0   0   252:0    10  DRIVE Onln  N  2.728 TB dflt N  N   none -      N  
 0 0   1   252:1    9   DRIVE Onln  N  2.728 TB dflt N  N   none -      N  
 0 0   2   252:2    11  DRIVE Onln  N  2.728 TB dflt N  N   none -      N  
 0 0   3   252:3    8   DRIVE Onln  N  2.728 TB dflt N  N   none -      N  
 0 -   -   252:7    13  DRIVE DHS   -  2.728 TB -    -  -   -    -      N  
 0 -   -   252:6    14  DRIVE DHS   -  2.728 TB -    -  -   -    -      N  
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
...
PD LIST :
=======
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
EID:Slt DID State DG     Size Intf Med SED PI SeSz Model                Sp Type 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
252:0    10 Onln   0 2.728 TB SATA HDD N   N  512B WDC WD30EFRX-68AX9N0 U  -    
252:1     9 Onln   0 2.728 TB SATA HDD N   N  512B WDC WD30EFRX-68AX9N0 U  -    
252:2    11 Onln   0 2.728 TB SATA HDD N   N  512B WDC WD30EFRX-68EUZN0 U  -    
252:3     8 Onln   0 2.728 TB SATA HDD N   N  512B WDC WD30EFRX-68EUZN0 U  -    
252:4    12 Onln   - 2.728 TB SATA HDD N   N  512B WDC WD30EFRX-68EUZN0 U  -    
252:6    14 DHS    0 2.728 TB SATA HDD N   N  512B WDC WD30EFRX-68EUZN0 U  -    
252:7    13 DHS    0 2.728 TB SATA HDD N   N  512B WDC WD30EFRX-68EUZN0 U  -    
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

In order to make the controller to reconsider the drive, set it to `good`:

```
storcli /c0 /e252 /s14 set good
```

`/e252` is the enclosure (`EID` in the output) and `/s14` is the slot (`Slt` in the output).

The state of the disk should now be `uGood`:

```
EID:Slt DID State DG     Size Intf Med SED PI SeSz Model                Sp Type 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
252:7    13 uGood  F 2.728 TB SATA HDD N   N  512B WDC WD30EFRX-68EUZN0 U  -
```

If the controller already knew the disk (it was installed before but for some reason, the controller thought the disk was bad), it may show up as `DHS` (dedicated hot spare).

To check that the disk is OK, run a self test:

```
smartctl -d megaraid,14  /dev/sdb -t long
```

`14` is the `DID` (Disk ID) from the `PD LIST` (`storcli /c0 show all`). That's the disk that you want. `/dev/sdb` is the Linux device which is attached to the megaraid driver. `-t long` starts a long self test.

To find the Linux device, use `lsscsi`:

```
 [6:2:0:0]    disk    LSI      MR9260-8i        2.13  /dev/sdb
```

To check the state of the self test, use `smartctl -d megaraid,14  /dev/sdb -c` or `smartctl -d megaraid,14  /dev/sdb -a`